# Django - get the last object of a model with many objects

Tags: python, django

I have two models. A father and a son model. And the relationship in the son model is:

```
father = models.ForeignKey(Father, related_name="father")
```

Now in the real database, I have 5 fathers, each father has 5 sons. I want to find sons with age 20.

```
father = Father.objects.all()
#how to find all sons with age 20?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title doesn't quite match your question and your question is missing information. But, is this what you want?

```
fathers = Fathers.objects.all()
sons = Son.objects.filter(father__in=fathers, age=20)
```

but, assuming all Sons have Fathers, you could just write this as

```
sons = Son.objects.filter(age=20)
```

If you are looking for all sons age 20 from one father:

```
father = Fathers.objects.get(id=101)
sons = Son.objects.filter(father=father, age=20)
```

This assumes that you have a different model for Father and Son (which is not a good design decision but it is what I understand from your question).

Comment: thanks. but here another small question. can i write a method for a model which takes parameter and use this method in template? can i do it?

Comment: Ask this as a separate question, and read the Stack Overflow FAQ.

Comment: (the answer is no, you must create a new template tag or call the function in the view)